# How to scroll without moving my cursor in Visual Studio Code from the Keyboard

Tags: visual-studio-code

I used to be able to scroll in `Visual Studio 2015` using some keyboard shortcuts in Windows doing something like <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>down</kbd>. It would effectively behave like a line by line viewport bump that did not modify where my cursor was inserted at. This is much like how scrolling with a mouse wheel does not move the cursor except its achieved from the keyboard.

I can't figure out how to do this on Visual Studio Code on a Mac.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

On my Mac <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow / Down Arrow</kbd> works similar to mouse scroll. This doesn't affect the cursor position.

Comment: That's ctrl + fn + arrow keys for people like me who took a while to figure this out.

Comment: Is horizontal scroll also possible?

Comment: @chrismarx per https://stackoverflow.com/a/74146435/336431 it is possible to configure keybinding to achieve horizontal scroll. I see that you've commented there as well! It seems to be working now.

Answer (score 34):

For me on mac what worked out was <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>Up/Down Arrow</kbd>

Comment: That's exactly what I need but the cursor doesn't move either. Is it possible to achieve this somehow?

Comment: is there's a way to make it move just like in Win, I mean smoothly in MacOS it just jumps?
Edit: found out that I can use `fn` +`ctr`+`up/down arrow` as @GittinJuggyWithIt suggested.

Comment: CMD + fn + Up/Down Arrow scrolls multiple lines for me (`scrollPageUp`). CTRL scrolls line by line (`scrollLineUp`)

Answer (score 30):

<kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>up/down arrow</kbd> did the trick for me on Mac  for moving just one line at a time.

Comment: This also works on Windows.

Comment: fn + command + up/down

Answer (score 14):

On Windows it is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>. On Mac I believe it will be <kbd>cmd</kbd> key instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>

Comment: It's ^ (control) on mac as well.

Answer (score 10):

#### Learning how to fish

If you're not using default shortcuts - such as when you came from a different editor and "imported the keybindings" (see [Keymap extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keymap-extensions)), you may want to:

1. Go to the [Keyboard Shortcuts editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-shortcuts-editor) at **File** > **Preferences** > **Keyboard Shortcuts**. (**Code** > **Preferences** > **Keyboard Shortcuts** on macOS)
2. Search for `scrollLine`
3. Check or change your current keybindings for `scrollLineUp` and `scrollLineDown`

[image]

Comment: yeah, but the default one is better cuz `ctr` + `up/down arrow` is already taken by the MacOS sys while it's possible to change it the functionality is indeed helpful I suggest sticking to the `fn` way (default).

Comment: @ShifraSec the whole point of this answer is to show how to read the shortcuts currently being set and/or change them if you're not happy with them!

Comment: IMHO you should consider replacing _XYZ is better_ for _I prefer XYZ_, for these assumptions are personal, even though you gave a valid reason.

Answer (score 4):

You can move one window height with <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down Arrow</kbd>

Comment: This is not what OP asked for, but is still useful. On same not, cmd + Up/Down Arrow would move cursor between start and end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

### Course scroll

- Scroll in large line heights (don't know exactly how much)

<kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Up/Down Arrow</kbd>

### Fine scroll

- Scroll in single line heights. Most answers have pointed this out.

<kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Up/Down Arrow</kbd>

Tested in Mac with VS Code 1.85.1 (Universal)

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Up/Down</kbd> Arrow to move. I have linux and the vim extention for vscode.
This command scrolls the view but not the cursor. So, keep that in mind.

Answer (score -2):

you can push the **shift** and **mouse roller**

Comment: question says from the keyboard but your answer involves using the mouse

Comment: does the mouse roller even move the cursor?

Comment: Why don't you just use standard vim keybindings to scroll? Or maybe Ctrl + F...

Comment: this moves the editor sideway (Hirozantaly).