# VsCode - Bind keyboard-key to scroll horizontaly

Tags: binding, visual-studio-code, key, horizontal-scrolling, ctrl

Is there a way to bind a keyboard-key to scroll horizontally?

I tried many different things and I cannot seem to put it together.

Comment: Horizontal scroll? Haven't heard that name in years... `"editor.wordWrap": "on",`

Comment: Horizontal scroll also works in the file explorer for example

Comment: Thank you alex, but with wordWrap it really gets difficult for me to read my code and to navigate through it. (Because I split my view a lot.).

Comment: Thanks Mark, but I do not really understand what you are tring to say. What do you mean by that and what is your advice?

Comment: There's an issue for that: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/143466  Upvote it to show support!

Answer (score 4):

Not a keyboard-only solution, but to scroll horizontally you can do <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>ScrollUp</kbd> / <kbd>ScrollDown</kbd>

Comment: Is this related to any VSC config? I am asking since I remember this worked for me before, but it doesn't work on the same VSC app recently. I'm not sure if this caused by touching any config by mistake for me.

Comment: Still works fine for me with the default settings in (Windows 10, VS Code v.1.63.2)

Answer (score 4):

There is a recent commit for new commands to scroll horizontally in the editor, see [commands for scrolling horizontally](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/feab94afadd3d9902950a8ab5417f90a6ff0e39d).. From the PR:

> Each of `scrollLeft` and `scrollRight` scroll two columns (this more
> or less matches the pace of the vertical scroll)

so those are the new commands.

For example:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+alt+left", "command": "scrollLeft" },
{ "key": "ctrl+alt+right", "command": "scrollRight" },
```

Comment: Afaict, this has only been released to insiders so far - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/143466

Comment: @chrismarx Those commands: `scrollLeft` and `scrollRight` are working fine in Stable now - have probably been in Stable for awhile.

Answer (score 1):

Not find keyboard-key solution, I provide an useful mouse-using method here.

vertial scrolling : `Mouse Wheel Up / Down`
horizontal scrolling : `Shift+Mouse Wheel Up / Down`

Answer (score 0):

There is one now with [VSCode 1.40 (Oct. 2019) for List/Tree](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40#_list-and-tree-keyboard-scrolling):

> You can now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> to scroll lists and trees using the keyboard.
>
> If horizontal scrolling is enabled, **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> will also scroll horizontally**.